# send 2Dimensional Listarray From Raspberry pi to the Arduino with I2c protocol

Tags: python, opencv, raspbian, i2c, smbus

im working on Computer vision (opencv )python and i had a result from the image , so this results is 2D List-arrays that should go to the Arduino by i2c buffer , so i realized that there is a library called smbus that interfacing the Raspberry pi with i2c ports so send and receive data , So i searched on References pages that give me some explanation about this Library but i didn't found eny thing useful...and all what i found is this sites which is not enough information

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol

http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki:linux:python:smbus:doc

so im indeed need eny  explanation how to send 2D Arrays Like (x,y) Coordinates 
 from Pi to Arduino with i2c buffer

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check [this repository](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/smart-lights/tree/master/semaphore/chip/drivers/python/grid_io). We connected a NTC CHIP to a Adafruit Trinket using I2C, but connecting the PI with the an Arduino should be very much the same.

The key file is the [I2C.py](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/smart-lights/blob/master/semaphore/chip/drivers/python/grid_io/i2c.py) file, which uses SMBus.

To talk to the Trinket Pro (ATMega328) we used the [trinket.py](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/smart-lights/blob/master/semaphore/chip/drivers/python/grid_io/trinket.py) file.

And the corresponding client code in the ATMega328, using the Arduino library, specially the Wire.h is located in the [hwthontrinket.ino](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/smart-lights/blob/master/semaphore/trinket/firmware/hwthontrinket/hwthontrinket.ino) file.

Finally, you can check how to use the classes in the [test files](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/smart-lights/blob/master/semaphore/chip/drivers/python/test/test_trinket_slave.py#L24). You basically need to pass the bus number and the address of the device.